# What is today's standard that might have replaced JXTA and P2P?

Tags: java, android, p2p

I've built an instant messaging application + voice chat(currently working on it) that is designed as centralized network. But when I was first starting out to build this app, I was interested in building it into P2P network, however, I had lack of references and information regarding to P2P, moreover I had concerns regarding to the client's security, so I've just decided build my app into centralized network. Recently I have discovered a P2P related framework called JXTA and it has motivated me to convert current app into P2P. But my question is, do majority of developers and organizations still use frameworks such as JXTA? or has it been replaced by something else? What is today's standard for this? (I know Torrent is based on P2P but do people still start to develop apps into p2p even tho there are today's standards like cloud?)

Comment: p2p and clouds are not standards but technologies which might work or not work in your particular scenario. Don't pull them to your project if they don't fit. Choose based on what you need to accomplish, not what a modern buzzword is.

Comment: I don't think "cloud" is a standard. Neither is P2P something. They're just general terms for a certain technique that you can implement in various ways. Maybe you could even build something that could be called both. If you want a client (peer) to be able to directly contact another peer, you might be implementing something called p2p. Or something going towards it.

Comment: You guys are right, they are all just technologies that has certain purposes to use. But in my case, I think P2P suits the best and I'm very interested in this, so i will just go and search more about it. Thank u for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no P2P standard.

JXTA is still used in production (we use it) but not maintained anymore following IP issues with Oracle; also the learning curve is rather steep.

For instant messaging type of network, you should look at [XMPP](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview)